# How do implement this regex function in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

The string should be 15 character maximum, composed of numbers only and there should be at least two one-character sized whitespace anywhere in the string.

It is easy to find the solution for numeric only, I'm getting stuck finding adding the condition for the whitespace.

I tried searching the most frequently asked regex question but couldn't find anything similar.

EDIT:

Additional conditions

- whitespaces cannot be next to each other
- they must not be placed in first or last character

Comment: How can it be "composed of numbers only" if it must contain whitespace?

Comment: sorry i meant numbers and whitespaces only. but there should be at least two one-character sized whitespace present

Comment: By "two one-charecter sized whitespaces" you mean that two consecutive spaces are not valid?

Comment: realskeptic : e.g.  "12 34543234 123"  <--- valid   "1  345678901234" <-- not valid. So yes the whitespaces must not be consecutive.

Comment: A asked about consecutive spaces. What about `12<space><space>345`?

Comment: to all: two consecutive whitespaces are not valid, they can be placed anywhere in the string but not next to each other. and there should be at least two whitepaces

Comment: So if your spaces can be "anywhere in the string", then `" 012345 "` is valid? (one space at either end)

Comment: khelwood: ooohhh sorry i forgot that other condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose for your demands, something like this would work:

```
\d+(\s\d+){2,}
```

But you'll need to check the length separately (e.g. `input.length() <= 15`).

This expressions says:

- Digits in the beginning.
- Then a single space followed by digits - at least two such combinations

This ensures that all spaces in the string are not before or after a space, and that there are at least two of them. It also prevents the spaces from being in the beginning or the end, and also allows for more than two of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex: `[0-9\s]{2,15}`

And in your Java code you check if there are three parts separated by a whitespace:

```
String input =...;
if (input.matches("[0-9\\s]{2,15}") && (input.split(" ").length == 3) ) {
     System.out.println("valid input");     
}
```

Edited: Leading and ending whitespaces, connected whitespaces are not allowed